# Is it possible to register 2 stylesheets via RegisterClientScriptBlock in an ASP.NET Custom Control (C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, registerclientscriptblock

I'm working on an ASP.NET Custom Control that uses a lot of JavaScript and CSS.  For maintenance purposes, it is easier to keep the files separate.  Before I declare my namespace, I've got the following code:

```
[assembly: WebResource("MyNamespace.Styles.colorbox.css", "text/css", PerformSubstitution = true)]
[assembly: WebResource("MyNamespace.Styles.pagination.css", "text/css")]
```

The CSS files are obviously in a subfolder called Styles.  I'm trying to register them in the OnInit of my page using the following code:

```
// Register colorbox css
cssColorbox = "<link href=\"" + Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(DoctypeSelectorControl), "MyNamespace.Styles.colorbox.css") + "\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />";
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(DoctypeSelectorControl), "cssFile", cssColorbox, false);

// Register pagination css
cssPagination = "<link href=\"" + Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(DoctypeSelectorControl), "MyNamespace.Styles.pagination.css") + "\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />";
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(DoctypeSelectorControl), "cssFile", cssPagination, false);
```

The first one loads up perfectly, but I don't even see a link for the second (pagination.css).  I wasn't sure if this was limited to one file this way or if there's a better way to handle this.

FYI: DoctypeSelectorControl is the name of the class if it wasn't obvious.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar in a project I worked on where I needed to move my CSS to a shared code library.  I was able to inject multiple files, the code below is an example of what I used.  Just make sure to specify your CSS files as embedded resources.

```
        string cssColorbox = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(),
            "MyNamespace.Styles.colorbox.css");

        string cssPagination = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(),
          "MyNamespace.Styles.pagination.css");


        HtmlGenericControl colorboxCss = new HtmlGenericControl("link");
        colorboxCss.Attributes.Add("href", cssColorbox);
        colorboxCss.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
        colorboxCss.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");


        HtmlGenericControl paginationCss = new HtmlGenericControl("link");
        paginationCss.Attributes.Add("href", cssPagination);
        paginationCss.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
        paginationCss.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");


        Page.Header.Controls.Add(colorboxCss);
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(paginationCss);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your actual issue, in the original post, is that you were using the same key.  Oddly, though, I would have expected the second overwrite the first.

Comment: You are right but the second CSS doesn't overwrite the first because RegisterClientScriptBlock checks if the key already exists before registering it, so it maintains always the first one...